# Makefile mistakenly confuses with nonexistant folder

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to compile backports with the following command line:

```
make KLIB=$CM_ROOT/out/target/product/$CM_BUILD/obj/KERNEL_OBJ KLIB_BUILD=$CM_ROOT/out/target/product/$CM_BUILD/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CM_ROOT/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi- defconfig-wcn36xx
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...make[2]: *** /home/user/android2/system/kernel/lge/mako: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

This is because the folder /home/user/android2/ does not exist.
Where did the folder android2 came from?

```
$CM_ROOT = /home/user/android-wcn36xx/system/
$CM_BUILD = mako

grep -r "android2" .
```

and

```
export | grep android2
```

returns nothing

Comment: What do you try to compile?

Comment: Well, I can confirm that I also don't see `android2` in the stuff that you included in your question .. which means that it's in something you *didn't* include in your question. Like the source code. Go to the root of the source and run `grep -l -r android2 .`, and see if that gets you any closer. Or tell us what you're compiling so that we can investigate independently. As it stands, this question can't be answered.

Comment: "grep -l -r android2 ." did not return anything.
I am trying to compile backports from here http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by running make clean and re-compiling in the source folder